# How to send out emails from a php file?

Tags: php, email, configure

I know about the mail function in php:
    `mail ($to, $subject, $msg_body,$headers);`

But since I cannot access my host's php.ini file, I've been provided with the following details:

```
SMTP host: mailout.host.com 
Port: 25 SMTP
Username: email@domainname.com
SMTP Password: not required
Authentication: Disabled
Encryption: Disabled
```

How can I use these details to send out emails?

EDIT: I used example pointed by Blender (below) and it seems to work fine for all  emails except  gmail. Any idea why? Is it to do with Fully Qualified Address?

Comment: This might help. It requires PEAR, which probably isn't installed on your server, though: http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Comment: Did you try to use `mail()`? For most shared hosting providers, it's already configured properly so you can easily use it without any modifications.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I did but for some reason it seems to send out emails on only hotmail addresses. Say for example if i send an email to abc@hotmail.com it will get delivered while abc@gmail.com wont get delivered. Therefore i'm trying configure things myself, if possible.

Comment: Your ISP's servers might be on some spam blacklists if other customers used them to send those nice viagra-selling emails. In this case using their SMTP might not help at all...

Comment: i just checked now using the example pointed by @Blender, it says:
"Failed to add recipient: abc@gmail.com [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 504, response: 5.5.2 : Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address)]"

Comment: Are you testing by using a local smtp server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org/) to send out emails through any email account you can login to, including gmail. It's very robust, but does have a bug where it uses a lot of memory for emails that have a lot of html in them.

Comment: i just read about PHPMailer and decided to give it a go. thanks.

Comment: PHPMailer used to be the "go to" mailer, but then was abandon. I used to use it years ago (PHP4). It was picked up by someone and a new version released, but doesn't seem to have much dev activity on it.

Answer (score 3):

[PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) is a very well known and widely used alternative

Check out the [SMTP mail example](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/BasicSmtp)

Comment: Have used this on more than one project.  Convenient and far more likely to get through than just using the raw email functions.

Comment: i've solved the problem for now, bul will definitely give PHPMailer a go.